# What is the fastest way to convert an IPv4 address to an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have about 1,000,000 IPv4 addresses, and I need to convert them to integers.

The methods I have tried:

1. `IPAddr.new(str).to_i`
2. `Socket.sockaddr_in(0, str)[4,4].unpack('L>')[0]`
3. `str.split('.').map(&:to_i).pack('CCCC').unpack('L>')[0]`
4. `str.split('.').map(&:to_i).inject(0) { |sum, v| (sum << 8) + v }`

However, all of them are at least 10x slower than this Python method:

```
struct.unpack('!L', socket.inet_aton(str))[0]
```

Is there any way other than write a C-Extension that is as fast as Python?

Here is the simple benchmark, in this benchmark, Python is 2x faster than Ruby, I'll see if the result will get bigger when processing random IPs.

Ruby:

```
require 'socket'
t1 = Time.now
10000000.times do
    Socket.sockaddr_in(0, '192.168.1.1')[4,4].unpack('L>')[0]
end
t2 = Time.now
puts t2 - t1
```

Python:

```
import time, struct, socket
t1 = time.time()
for i in xrange(10000000):
    struct.unpack('!L', socket.inet_aton('192.168.1.1'))[0]
t2 = time.time()
print t2 - t1
```

Comment: So...why doesn't `IPAddr.new(str).to_i` work for you?  That seems to be *the* most straightforward way to get it done...

Comment: I will use this script to process some large log files, so the performance really matters and I wonder why Python is so fast in this situation.

Comment: If you only have a million why does it really matter? The conversion itself is clocking for me at 4.5e-05 times a million is like 45s.

Comment: I have many files like this and I have to process one file at a time on demand (It's impossible to pre-process all the files). So I have to wait one minute to get a result each time I run the script while Python can process a million addresses in 5s.

Comment: Will your IPs repeat so memoization is an option?

Comment: How do you prove that the Ruby methods are at least 10 times slower than the Python one? Can you show the code?

Comment: #2 is the most analogous to the Python example, and indeed, benchmarking shows it to be about 4X faster than #1. I was able to speed it up a bit by using a pack format of `N` instead of `L>` or `L!`.

Comment: We need a lot more information about your entire process. How are you reading the files, slurping them or using line-by-line I/O? How do you identify the IP address in the line, is the line only the IP or do you parse it? The problem with statements like "language x is faster than y" is you haven't shown your proof. When people are more familiar with on language they tend to write better code so we can't tell what you've done and whether it's a good practice for Ruby, resulting in a very broad question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really difficult to help you as we don't necessarily have access to Python or your Ruby vs. Python code benchmarking both, and us writing both would be invalid as then you'd have to shoehorn anything we do into your code, potentially slowing or breaking it. However, here's something that might be useful to begin honing your code to improve its speed:

```
require 'fruity'
require 'ipaddr'

STR = '192.168.0.0'
compare do
  ipaddr_new { IPAddr.new(STR).to_i }
  sockaddr_in { Socket.sockaddr_in(0, STR)[4,4].unpack('L>')[0] }
  pack1 { STR.split('.').map(&:to_i).pack('CCCC').unpack('L>')[0] }
  pack2  { STR.split('.').map(&:to_i).inject(0) { |sum, v| (sum << 8) + v } }
end
```

Running that results in:

```
# >> Running each test 512 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> sockaddr_in is faster than pack2 by 30.000000000000004% ± 1.0%
# >> pack2 is faster than pack1 by 19.999999999999996% ± 1.0%
# >> pack1 is faster than ipaddr_new by 2.9x ± 0.1
```

Comparing your `N` change to `L>` or `L!` shows:

```
Socket.sockaddr_in(0, STR)[4,4].unpack('L>')[0] # => 3232235520
Socket.sockaddr_in(0, STR)[4,4].unpack('L!')[0] # => nil
Socket.sockaddr_in(0, STR)[4,4].unpack('N')[0] # => 3232235520
```

So `L!` is invalid.

```
compare do
  sockaddr_in1 { Socket.sockaddr_in(0, STR)[4,4].unpack('L>')[0] }
  sockaddr_in2 { Socket.sockaddr_in(0, STR)[4,4].unpack('L!')[0] }
  sockaddr_in3 { Socket.sockaddr_in(0, STR)[4,4].unpack('N')[0] }
end

# >> Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> sockaddr_in2 is faster than sockaddr_in1 by 10.000000000000009% ± 10.0% (results differ:  vs 3232235520)
# >> sockaddr_in1 is similar to sockaddr_in3
```

Comment: Your benchmarks would be more meaningful if run against more than one IP address. `ipaddrs = 500_000.times.map { IPAddr.new(rand(2**32), Socket::AF_INET).to_s }`

Comment: My benchmarks are to show the OP that it's easy to benchmark and obtain usable results. The deltas show significant differences in speed due to the expressions used, and parsing one address vs another isn't going to change that.

Comment: Your first point is fair. To your second point, it's not about parsing performance between different IP addresses, it's about performance of the different methods in aggregate. The OP is asking about handling millions of IP addresses, so any benchmarking should take that into consideration. A benchmark of a single line of Ruby run one time is nearly meaningless.

Comment: Fruity doesn't run "one time". It's more sophisticated than that. And, you are more than welcome to add a more sophisticated benchmarking example.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I'll have to start using fruity!

Answer (score 1):

Here are benchmark results using a large selection of randomly-generated IPv4 addresses:

```
       user     system      total        real
IPAddr:  3.240000   0.000000   3.240000 (  3.242000)
Socket:  0.760000   0.000000   0.760000 (  0.759157)
pack:    1.790000   0.010000   1.800000 (  1.797654)
reduce:  1.570000   0.010000   1.580000 (  1.579099)
ipgem:   4.060000   0.000000   4.060000 (  4.061129)
```

As I mentioned in my comment above, the `Socket.sockaddr_in` technique seems to be the fastest. I'll attach the benchmarking code below.

One thing that occurred to me as I was working on this was that most of these techniques are IPv4-specific. Considering the [impending](http://www.networkworld.com/article/2985340/ipv6/arin-finally-runs-out-of-ipv4-addresses.html) switch to IPv6, it's probably unwise to limit your code to IPv4. If this were a one-off, fine, but considering your performance concerns I'm guessing this is meant to be reusable.

If you really want to crush the benchmark, you should look into processing the log(s) in parallel using something like [Parallel](https://github.com/grosser/parallel) or [forkoff](https://github.com/ahoward/forkoff). Use all of the cores.

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'ipaddr'
require 'ipaddress'

n = 500_000
family = Socket::AF_INET # IPv4
ipaddrs = n.times.map { IPAddr.new(rand(2**32), family).to_s }

Benchmark.bm do |x|
  x.report('IPAddr:') { ipaddrs.map { |str| IPAddr.new(str).to_i } }
  x.report('Socket:') { ipaddrs.map { |str| Socket.sockaddr_in(0, str).byteslice(4, 4).unpack('N').first } }
  x.report('pack:  ') { ipaddrs.map { |str| str.split('.').map(&:to_i).pack('CCCC').unpack('L>').first } }
  x.report('reduce:') { ipaddrs.map { |str| str.split('.').map(&:to_i).reduce(0) { |sum, v| (sum << 8) + v } } }
  x.report('ipgem: ') { ipaddrs.map { |str| IPAddress.parse(str).to_u32 } }
end
```

Running a similar benchmark in Python3 (using the snippet you provided as a starting point) yields a time of about 0.242 seconds on the same machine, so about three times faster than the fastest Ruby version.

```
import time, struct, socket, random

n = 500000
ipaddrs = [socket.inet_ntoa(struct.pack('>I', random.randint(1, 0xffffffff))) for i in range(n)]

t1 = time.time()
for ipaddr in ipaddrs:
    struct.unpack('!L', socket.inet_aton(ipaddr))[0]
t2 = time.time()
print(t2 - t1)
```

Comment: You left out an obvious one: `x.report('gsub:') { ipaddrs.map { |str| str.sub!('.', '').to_i } }` ... it's destructive and isn't as fast as Socket, but it's not far behind...

Comment: That's not what we're talking about here. :-) Removing the periods from an IP address and concatenating the octets is not the same as converting it to a binary integer. Play around with an IP address calculator and note the binary/decimal forms. http://www.csgnetwork.com/ipaddconv.html